# How to use backticks in linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash

From the 《Bash Guide for Beginners》 ：

```
3.4.5. Command substitution

Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command itself. Command substitution
occurs when a command is enclosed like this:

$(command)

or like this using backticks:

\`command`

Bash performs the expansion by executing COMMAND and replacing the command substitution with the
standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted, but
they may be removed during word splitting.

    franky ~> echo `date`
    Thu Feb 6 10:06:20 CET 2003



When the old−style backquoted form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when
followed by "$", "`", or "\".

The first backticks not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.

When using the "$(COMMAND)" form, all characters between the parentheses make up the
command; none are treated specially.
```

In this passage, there is one sentence I don't understand.

```
The first backticks not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.
```

Can you provide examples to explain it in more detail?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Its better to use `$()` than backticks. But the last sentence means that if there is a backslash before a backtick i.e `\\``, then it will be seen as a literal backtick and not a terminator to the command.

Comment: @User112638726  thank you for your comment! But can you tell me how to use it(i.e:  \\` ) and when should I use it in linux, what significance for not terminates command? sorry,My English is very poor,i don't know can you understand me.

Comment: Honestly, there should ever be a reason to use backticks instead of `$()`. The reason you would escape a backtick would typically be to nest them inside each other, but you really don't want to be nesting backticks.

Comment: @User112638726 thank you for your advice! i just want to know. Thanks again for your kind help!

Comment: @User112638726 I seem to understand, ha-ha! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author meant the first not-escaped backtick.

Dummy example:

```
echo `command \` arg`
```

First the backtick between command and arg is escaped with backslash, so the substitution is closed by the last backtick.

Comment: You need to escape the backticks when answering or it will put them in a code block.

Comment: @User112638726 Thank you. It's fixed now.

Comment: @tsv.dimitrov Although I don't really understand,but thank you for your help.

Comment: @tsv.dimitrov I seem to understand, ha-ha! thanks a lot!